# How to solve difficult geometric sequence problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a_1, a_2, a_3, ...$ are terms of a geometric sequence with common ratio $r \neq 1,$ show that:

$$(a_1-a_2)^2 + (a_2-a_3)^2 + (a_3-a_4)^2 + \cdots +(a_n-a_{n+1})^2 = \frac{a_1^2(1-r)(1-r^{2n})}{1+r}.$$

This can be written as:

$$(a_1-a_1r)^2 + (a_1r-a_1r^2)^2 + (a_1r^2-a_1r^3)^2 + \cdots +(a_1r^{n-1}-a_1r^n)^2.$$

Factorising $r$ gives:

$$(a_1(1-r))^2 + (a_1r(1-r))^2 + (a_1r^2(1-r))^2 + \cdots +(a_1r^{n-1}(1-r))^2.$$

From here, I am unsure how best to proceed.

Over to you mathematicians, how do I show this equality?

Comment: Please proofread your plus and minus signs.

Comment: Done.@John Bentin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** Group the numbers and you will have:

$$(a_1(1-r))^2 + (a_1r(1-r))^2 + (a_1r^2(1-r))^2 + \cdots +(a_1r^{n-1}(1-r))^2 = a_1^2(1-r)^2(1 + r^2 + r^4 + \cdots +r^{2(n-1)})$$

Now use:

$$\frac{1 - r^n}{1-r} = 1 + r + r^2 + \cdots +r^{n-1}$$

Comment: I understand the grouping but where do you get the equation at the bottom @Stefan4024

Comment: @TomFinet It's a well know equation. Multiply both sides by $(1-r)$ and after cancelations you will see that this identity is true. It's the formula for calculating the sum of a geometric series. In the formula substitute $r$ with $r^2$ and you will see how it will help you with the problem.

Comment: Thanks actually I was pretty close just needed to factorise a little more. 